# idxmax() giving an index that cannot be found.

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

Greetings I have an df with an index from 0 to 00.6279999999999999.

I used idxmax() to find the index of the max variable in one column - df[Column A]. 
Lets say the index is 0.5579999999999998 and I assigned it to variable max
e.g: max = df[Column A].idxmax

However when I try to locate the element/variable at the at index in another column (Column B), using df[Column B].iloc(max)

I receive the errror: 
No axis named 0.5579999999999998 for object type

But when I manually check, I can see the index 0.5579999999999998.

Is it a type error? or just me being silly?

Thank you in advance for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with tiny values like this, there's always the danger of floating point inaccuracies. What idxmax() returns may differ from what exists in the index by as low as 20 digits of precision.

The first suggestion I'd offer is to either scale the index, round it off, or not have it as an index at all.

For now, to access that particular row, use `np.isclose` and index the DataFrame with a mask:

```
df[np.isclose(df.index, df['Column A'].idxmax())]
```